# What is the difference between "truc" and "chose"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the difference between "truc" and "chose"? In what contexts are the two words used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Chose** (du latin *causa* → « affaire ») a servi à désigner des termes divers. Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle il développe le sens actuel d'objet non spécifié (par opposition à objet) et sert aussi à désigner une personne dont on a oublié le nom.

**Truc** est un mot issu d'une racine indo-européenne qui a donné des mots comme *trucar* (cogner, heurter en ancien provençal) et le russe *trud* « labeur, besogne ».  Le mot est arrivé en français au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner un coup d'adresse, une ruse, puis au XVIII <sup>e</sup> siècle un moyen adroit de se tirer d'affaire, et spécialement un savoir-faire dans un métier ou un art particulier qu'on ne veut pas révéler. C'est de cette dernière acceptation que vient l'un des emplois actuels (attesté depuis la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle) pour désigner un objet ou une personne qu'on ne veut pas ou ne peut pas nommer.

Références trouvées dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey).

#### Usage :

**Chose** est le mot courant actuel pour désigner quelque chose ou quelqu'un qu'on ne veut pas ou ne peut pas nommer.
En français familier il existe plusieurs termes synonymes : truc, mais aussi machin, machin-chose, machin-truc...

Bien qu'historiquement l'usage de **truc** pour désigner quelque chose ou quelqu'un qu'on ne veut pas nommer soit entré plus récemment dans la langue, c'est actuellement considéré comme familier, mais moins que machin, machin-chose, machin-truc...

---

**Chose** (from latin "causa" → "thing") was used to connote various terms. It started being used with its present meaning in the 16th century to indicate an unspecified object (as opposed to "object") and it is used to designate someone whose name we have forgotten.

**Truc** (from Indo-European root that gave words like Provençal "trucar" ("to hit") and russian "trud" (work, labour). "Truc" arrived in French in the 13th century to designate something artful, skillful. In the 18th century it was used to designate a clever trick one would use to get by without wanting to explain how. Hence the present use of the word to designate something or someone one does not want or does not know how to name.

#### Usage:

**Chose** is nowadays the usual word to designate something or someone we don't want or can't name. Although having taken that meaning earlier than "chose", "**truc**" is nowadays the colloquial word to designate something or someone we don't want or can't name. There are other familiar terms (even more familiar than "truc") to designate something or someone we don't want or can't name: machin, machin-chose, machin-truc...

Note that in French "chose" and "truc" can designate both, an object, or a person. Whereas in English you'd use thingy (for "chose"), thingummy/whatsit for "truc", and a different word when talking about a person (so-and-so for "chose" and lots of words exist for "truc").

Comment: j'ai lu votre réponse avec une grande surprise. Merci pour vos informations intéressantes.

Comment: Dommage que tu ne parles pas de bidule.

Answer (score 7):

They both have a similar meaning when describing some unnamed or unidentified "thingy". "Chose" is here slighty more formal.

"Truc" might also mean "trick".

---

Les deux peuvent nommer un objet indéterminé ou non identifié. "Chose" est alors légèrement plus soutenu.

"Truc" peut aussi signifier *trick* (astuce, tour, combine).